# clang tool against individual file

Tags: ios, xcode, clang

Is it possible to run clang tool (static analysis) for individual file in iOS (Objective-c)?

Tried in terminal against AppDelegate.m 
Following is the error:

```
clang AppDelegate.h -fsyntax-only
AppDelegate.h:9:9: fatal error: 'UIKit/UIKit.h' file not found
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
        ^
1 error generated.
```

Answer (score 0):

You shoud use xcrun to let clang find all required frameworks first:

```
xcrun -sdk iphoneos clang -ObjC -fsyntax-only AppDelegate.h
```

Answer (score 0):

Please install them using the following command: `xcode-select --install` and try again.